# HEAD request receives "403 forbidden" while GET "200 ok"?

Tags: http-headers, get, bots, head

after several months having the site disappear from search results in every major search engine, I finally found out a possible reason.

I used WebBug to investigate server header. See the difference if the request is HEAD or GET.

**HEAD Sent data:**

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.attu.it
Connection: close
Accept: */*
User-Agent: WebBug/5.0
```

**HEAD Received data:**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 10 Aug 2010 23:01:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**GET Sent data:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.attu.it
Connection: close
Accept: */*
User-Agent: WebBug/5.0
```

**GET Received data:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 Aug 2010 23:06:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Jan 2010 08:58:01 GMT
ETag: "671f91b-2d2-47ca362815840"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 722
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

// HTML code here
```

Now, browsers by default send a GET request (at least this is what firebug says). Is it possible that crawlers send a HEAD request instead? If so, why only this server responds with a 403, while other servers from other sites I'm mantaining do not?

In case it's important, the only line present in .htaccess is (unless my client changed it, as they don't want to give me access to their server)

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks @Ryk. FireBug and Fiddler both send GET requests, which get 200 (or 300) responses. As expected. So I guess it's either a server bad setting (even though it's strange as the hosting is from a major company with millions of clients) or something they put in the .htaccess. They will have to let me look into their account.

The second part of my question was if that could be the cause of the website not appearing in any search engine (*site:www.attu.it* gives no results). Any thought?

**UPDATE 2**
After some fiddling around, it turns out there was the phpMyAdmin robots-blocking .htaccess in the root directory, that caused any request from robots to be sent back with a 403 Forbidden

Comment: It's a bug with the server, the client want it fixed, they should give you at least some access. At the very least, ask them if they could see a copy of the current .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing Fiddler and looking carefully at the request. I have seen sometimes that an icon on the page that is in a folder that requires authentication causes a 403 to be returned.

Fiddler will give you a good idea, and you can also try Firefox and install FireBug add-on and inspecting the page for errors.

Looking at the site I get a bunch of 404's for the favicon.ico, but apart from that when I do a simple GET request I get a 200 OK, but when I do a HEAD,  I also get a 403. Looking into it now.

UPDATE: I think it might be a configuration on the Apache server, but not 100% sure. http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/head.html

UPDATE2: Reading this http://www.pubbs.net/200811/httpd/17210-usershttpd-how-to-reject-head-request.html makes me believe that your Apache server could be set to reject HEAD requests. In that case it will return a 403.

Comment: @mjsarfatti - I am not sure, but if the crawlers/robots use the HEAD request to crawl sites, then yes, you will have an issue.

Comment: I found curl easier than fiddler

Answer (score 2):

Some administrator writes in the httpd.conf

<Limit PUT DELETE COPY MOVE>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Deny from all
                        Allow from 10.0
</Limit>

<LimitExcept PUT DELETE COPY MOVE>
                      Order deny,allow
                      Deny from all
</LimitExcept>

This produce "Forbidden" to a HEAD request. You should check this.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem because I was using signed URLs.

Each signed URLs is good for only one method (e.g. GET, or HEAD). If you want to use multiple methods, you will have to have multiple URLs.

Comment: I think this is the problem I am currently getting with my Gradle build : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253755/gradle-failing-to-download-dependency-when-head-request-fails. Do you have any idea how to work around that ?