# Retrieve file size with Curl when HEAD returns 403 but GET is 200?

Tags: curl

Firstly this is not a duplicate of the multiple questions already asked about just simply getting file size from by requesting headers. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450402/how-to-retrieve-downloadable-file-size-with-curl-command
Etc.

I actually started by reading them when i needed to to get the file size of a remote file and determined that running curl with -I/--head should give me a Content-Length: that i can use. Instead for me it gives me a 403 error.

```
# not posting full curl command for sake of privacy and NSFW link
# but it was derived from firefox's copy as curl command result
curl -I 'https://somedomain.xyz/files/video.mp4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0' -H 'Referer: xyz' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=xyz' 

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 17:41:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Cf-Railgun: direct (starting new WAN connection)
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: xyz-YUL
```

Here suggest its because of missing cookie/referer 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/why-would-curl-and-wget-result-in-a-403-forbidden
I tried all that were listed and no difference. Still 403.

Here suggest the site admin could be blocking it [HEAD request receives "403 forbidden" while GET "200 ok"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454286/head-request-receives-403-forbidden-while-get-200-ok)

What is odd to me is that if i try to download the file curl instantly reports the size in the total column, although in human readable form.

```
curl 'https://somedomain.xyz/files/video.mp4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0' -H 'Referer: xyz' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=xyz' 

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0  384M    0 3148k    0     0  1594k      0  0:04:07  0:00:01  0:04:06 1594k
```

How is curl achieving this and can i utilize it to obtain size rather than requesting the header?
Alternatively, is there a way i just get the header request to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use `curl -X GET -I`with URL and cookies.
Referer and user-agent weren't necessary.

For comparison

Header request `curl -I 'https://somedomain.xyz/files/video.mp4' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=xyz'`

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 27 Mar 2020 17:44:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Cf-Railgun: direct (starting new WAN connection)
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: XYZ-YUL
```

GET header request `curl -X GET -I 'https://somedomain.xyz/files/video.mp4' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=xyz'`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Mar 2020 17:45:14 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 9895038
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Cf-Railgun: direct (waiting for pending WAN connection)
Expires: Tue, 31 Dec 2030 23:30:45 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Mar 2020 16:52:51 CET
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: XYZ-YUL
```